# Sort an array alphabetically based on a search input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

If I have an array such as:

```
["Adambb", "Andrebw", "Bob", "Billy", "Sandrab", "Xaviercb"]
```

And I type in a search box (for example) "B", how can I reorder the array in JavaScript with the results that match the string closest (also alphabetized), first?

For example, typing in "B" into the search box would reorder the array to:

```
["Billy", "Bob", "Adambb", "Andrebw", "Sandrab", "Xaviercb"]
```

I want the array to reorder much like any search system should work. For some reason I cannot find this answer anywhere online. Either I am not formulating my question right or I just can't find anything similar to my question.

Comment: use `array.sort()` and pass in a function to choose the closest to "b"

Comment: What do you mean by closest to "b"?

Comment: get the character code of the search term e.g. "b".charCodeAt(0); and do them same in the sort function, with the closest charCode to "b" char code.

Comment: I should add that the search term can be any number of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to check is the strings start with the entered value, and make a decision about the order.

- When `a` and `b` starts with the entered value make a string comparison.
- If a starts with the entered value and `b` doesn't then place `a` at the beginning.
- If `b` starts with the entered value and a doesn't then place `b` at the beginning.
- Otherwise, make the default string comparison.

```js
var array = [{id: "157", tag: "Adambb", course: "Adambb - Calculus I"}, {id: "158", tag: "Andrebw", course: "Andrebw - Ca I"}, {id: "159", tag: "Bob", course: "Bob - Cass I"}, {id: "160", tag: "Billy", course: "Billy - uus I"}, {id: "161", tag: "Sandrab", course: "Sandrab - allus I"}, {id: "162", tag: "Xaviercb", course: "Xaviercb - Cal I"}];

var input = 'Sa'; // Changed to illustrate the behavior.

var sorted = array.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a.course.startsWith(input) && b.course.startsWith(input)) return a.course.localeCompare(b.course);
   else if (a.course.startsWith(input)) return -1;
   else if (b.course.startsWith(input)) return 1;
     
   return a.course.localeCompare(b.course);;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An alternative is to check if the strings contain the entered value and make a decision about the order.

- When `a` and `b` contain the entered value make a string comparison.
- If `a` contains the entered value and `b` doesn't then place `a` at the beginning.
- If `b` contains the entered value and `a` doesn't then place `b` at the beginning.
- Otherwise, make the default string comparison.

```js
var array = [{id: "157", tag: "Adambb", course: "Adambb - Calculus I"}, {id: "158", tag: "Andrebw", course: "Andrebw - Ca I"}, {id: "159", tag: "Bob", course: "Bob - Cass I"}, {id: "160", tag: "Billy", course: "Billy - uus I"}, {id: "161", tag: "Sandrab", course: "Sandrab - allus I"}, {id: "162", tag: "Xaviercb", course: "Xaviercb - Cal I"}];

var input = 'r'; // Changed to illustrate the behavior.

var sorted = array.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a.course.indexOf(input) !== -1 && b.course.indexOf(input) !== -1) return a.course.localeCompare(b.course);
   else if (a.course.indexOf(input) !== -1) return -1;
   else if (b.course.indexOf(input) !== -1) return 1;
     
   return a.course.localeCompare(b.course);
});

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Ele To clarify, my array is actually an array of objects. I probably should have mentioned this in the question but I did not think it would matter. For example, 
`[ {id: "157", tag: "MAT 101", course: "MAT 101 - Calculus I"} ... {...} ]`. I would like to sort the objects based on the how the `course` matches the search term. I have modified your code to look as such `if (a['course'].indexOf(input) ...`, however, it does not sort at all. Do you know why it wouldn't work for an array of objects?

Comment: @Nic I'm validating.

Comment: This is really weird but mine still doesn't for some reason. Here is what I see in the console when I print out my `array`: `(2103) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]...` If I open up one of the indices I see: `{id: "157", tag: "MAT 101", course: "MAT 101 - Calculus I"}`. However, when I run your code on the array and log the output it returns the same array without the sorting. No errors during the sorting either.

Comment: Also, strangely enough I just ran your code verbatim and it did not sort using an input of `b`...

Comment: Ahhh. It is case sensitive. That explains it all.

Comment: Now for some reason adding `.toLowerCase()` makes the sorting no longer work. I use `s` as my input and convert all `a.course` and `b.course` and it does not sort "Sandrab" first.

Comment: @Nic hehehehe I want to remove this answer because is not helping!!

Comment: @Nic according to the current data in the answer that makes sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167305/discussion-between-nic-and-ele).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to this in javascript.
You can use a compareFunction of sorts which you can pass as a parameter to Array.sort method.

```
var compareFunction = function(a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf('B') < b.indexOf('B')) {
     return 1
  } else {
     return -1
  }
}
var arrToSort = ["Adambb", "Andrebw", "Bob", "Billy", "Sandrab", "Xaviercb"];
console.log(arrToSort.sort(compareFunction));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. It gets the *first* character char codes (ASCII) and sorts by the distance to this code. You will want to improve it by doing this for all characters in the string, not just the first character (zeroth index). Bearing in mind it doesn't take into account lowercase letters. You can use String.toLowerCase() to improve this.

```js
let arr = ["Adambb", "Andrebw", "Bob", "Billy", "Sandrab", "Xaviercb"];
let arrCodes = arr.map(s=>({code:s.charCodeAt(0), value:s}));
let searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input");
searchInput.addEventListener("change", function(){
  let val = this.value;
  if(val){
    const code = val.charCodeAt(0);
    let sorted = arrCodes.sort(function(a, b){
      let distA = Math.abs(a.code-code);
      let distB = Math.abs(b.code-code);
      return distA-distB;
    });
    final = sorted.map(s=>s.value);
    console.log("sorted:", final);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px) !important;
}
```

```html
<input id="search-input" type="text" maxlength="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample snippet that does the filtered sorting. Might require some more refinement. Also I did not consider the casing in this solution so is case sensitive.

So basically in your sort function you evaluate the following conditions:

1. x starts with the filter value but not y;
2. x does not start with the filter value but y does;
3. both x and y starts with the filter value; so you want to start comparing with the parts of string after removing the filter value;
4. both x and y doesn't start with the filter value; you want to retain their position based on the normal sorting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="textFilter" type="text"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var names = ["Adambb", "Andrebw", "Bob", "Billy", "Sandrab", "Xaviercb"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = names;

function myFunction() {
 var filterValue = document.getElementById("textFilter").value;
        
  // sort with a function
 names.sort(function(x,y) {     
        if( x.startsWith(filterValue) && !y.startsWith(filterValue))
        {
         return -1;
        }
        else if (!x.startsWith(filterValue) && y.startsWith(filterValue))
        {
         return 1;
        }
        else if(x.startsWith(filterValue) && y.startsWith(filterValue))
        {
         var x2 = x.substring(filterValue.length-1);
          var y2 = y.substring(filterValue.length-1);
            
            return x2 > y2;
        }
        else
        {
         return x > y;
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = names;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```